# Proving a group has a Sylow subgroup by the Sylow theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that the group $G$ with cardinality $399=19 \cdot 21$ has a unique 19-Sylow subgroup.
Following one of the Sylow theorems, $n_p=1 $mod $p, $ and $n_p|21$, one gets that the options for $n_p$ are $ n_p={1,20,39,58,...},$ and $n_p={0,21,42,63,...}$. The intersection of these two sets does not contain the number $1$ as expected.

What is wrong in my proceeding?

Many thanks.

Comment: $21$ is not a prime number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how did you get to the $0,21,42,63,...$ sequence. Since $n_p|21$ the options are $1,3,7,21$. However, we also know that $n_p\equiv 1$(mod$19$), so it must be $n_p=1$.

Comment: You are right. I worked with $n_p=21s$ which is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first Sylow theorem guarantees you that there exists a 19-Sylow group, since $19\nmid 21$. According to the third Sylow theorem, we have that the number of 19-Sylow groups, $n_{19}$, must satisfy $n_{19}\equiv 1\:\text{mod}\; 19$ and $n_{19}|21$. Therefore $n_{19}\in \lbrace 1,3,7,21\rbrace$. The only one of these possibilities that solves the congruence is $n_{19} =1$.